# Strange error in MonthCalendar just started happening out of nowhere

Tags: c#, winforms

This crash report started coming through 2 days ago from a lot of our users. There have been no updates to our code, and this error is happening on multiple versions. Some of these versions are years old so it's not like an update broke something. It's a .NET 4.0 app using Infragistics 2014 Vol 2. Infragistics support seem to think it's a bug in the MonthCalendar for Windows Forms but I haven't been able to find anything online. From the screenshot with the crash dump it looks like all the users are doing is clicking to dropdown the calendar, when they get this error. I haven't been able to replicate it.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
at System.Windows.Forms.MonthCalendar.WndProc(Message& m)
at Infragistics.Win.MonthDropDownWithUIPermissions.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Does anyone have any ideas what could be causing this? It's critical, and I have nowhere to even start.

Comment: That method doesn't seem to throw anything. http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/MonthCalendar.cs,f3040a7a7e228f58

Comment: Could it be that those machines got .Net framework updates ? do you have a machine with un-updated .Net framework 4.0 to test ?

Comment: @SLaks I know but this exception is being thrown every 5 or 10 minutes by one of our users. They have a mix of Win7 SP1, Win8 and a few on Vista. I can't get the error to happen on my machine and I have the latest updates. I can keep trying to replicate it.

Comment: It has to be related to Windows Updates because it only started happening on Tuesday. I can't seem to find anything in the list of updates that would have affected this, most of the updates are security updates for .NET 3.5 and 4.5, and Windows 8.1 This issue is happening on all OS's.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks for Mangist response. It help me find the cause of the problem. I was having problems with the **MonthCalendar** control, the source of the problem was control's internal methods for displaying bolded dates. I was filling the *BoldedDates* property with an array of Dates. That was causing the control to automatically call the *UpdateBoldedDates()* function and there was the crash.
All I did was that I replaced the code by adding bolded date one by one (there is no performance loss). When doing this, the *UpdateBoldedDates()* function **must** be called manually ( which saved my life :) ).
So, after filling up the *MonthCalendar* with bolded dates I used the "workaround" and called the *UpdateBoldedDates()* function in the worker thread. Here is my code (in Visual Basic.NET):

```
Private Sub UpdateBoldedDatesWT()
    mcCalendar.UpdateBoldedDates()
End Sub

Public Sub LoadBoldedDates()

    Dim bDates As List(Of Date)

    Try
        Dim dExt As New DatesHelper(sqlConn)
        bDates = dExt.GetAppointmentDates(mcCalendar.SelectionStart)
        mcCalendar.RemoveAllBoldedDates()

        For Each d As Date In bDates
            mcCalendar.AddBoldedDate(d)
        Next

        mcCalendar.BeginInvoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf UpdateBoldedDatesWT))
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error loading bolded dates")
    End Try

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a Microsoft Hotfix rollup 3064711 for the Crash:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3064711

Problems solved:

Assume that you are running a Windows Forms application. When the application disposes a System.Windows.Forms.MonthCalendar control in certain cases, the following InvalidOperationException exception will be thrown:
*Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.*

MS Connect Thread:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1345128/errors-after-installing-kb3023222-update

Comment: The essential part of the answer is in posts above. @d1no just posted the solution provided by Microsoft, which is the hotfix preventing the issue in question. This issue will become obsolete since the solution is integrated in windows updates and will not ocurre again (hopefully). Therefore, such comments are not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

After I installed the Windows updates from Tuesday and rebooted my PC, I could replicate the problem easily. It turns out this (6 year old!) code now crashes .NET even though it's been working for years. I have code in one of my forms to close up the calendar after the user chooses a date. Now that line of code is crashing, so I have removed it. It looks like the calendar automatically closes up now without needing that anymore.

```
private void dtpServiceDate_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dtpServiceDate.CloseUp(); // <-- this line crashes now
```

Commenting out that line fixes it.

I wish Microsoft wouldn't release breaking changes to the framework like this, now I have to update thousands of users apps that were working just fine.

EDIT: I have received an answer from Infragistics at least for a workaround. They are hesitant to change their code as it hasn't changed since 2002.

```
private void dtpServiceDate_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.dtpServiceDate.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(this.CloseCalendar));
        }

       private void CloseCalendar()
      {
            dtpServiceDate.CloseUp();
      }
```

Comment: I have the same problem, I don't know where the problem is... It is strange, the problem started in a same day... I can't fix it and I don't know why it happens. I have another machine which runs the app perfectly but all other machines are having the same issue. Maybe it is caused by some update. I can't find anything, tried hundreds of searches.. I'm very angry, does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: @Marjan it was definitely caused by Windows Update "KB3023222 (for Win 8) or KB3023224 (for Win 7). The reason your other machine runs fine is because it doesn't have the latest updates installed.The bug is confirmed by Infragistics. The fix is to invoke the CloseCalendar() call on the UI thread this.dtpServiceDate.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(this.CloseCalendar));  That will fix the error

Comment: In my case the cause of that error was the Bolded dates functionality. I  have tried the both options by setting an array of bolded dates and setting them one by one. In the case of the bolded dates array (array of DateTime) the control was invoking the 'UpdateBoldedDates()' function which was causing the crash. In the case of setting bolded dates one by one, by calling the 'AddBoldedDate(theDate)' function, I had to call 'UpdateBoldedDates()' manually. If I didn't call that the exception wouldn't occur. It crashed when when I uncommented that function. The control is MonthCalendar.

Comment: I am also having a problem with Bolded dates. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I have posted my solution in separate answer. Thanks!